# Can't adjust brightness on my laptop

Tags: 10.10, acer, brightness, aspire

I'm having difficulty in adjusting brightness on my Acer Aspire 4740:

- Screen     14.1-inch glossy LED-backlit, 1366x768 res
- CPU    Intel Core i5-430M 2.26-GHz
- RAM    1GB DDR3
- HDD    320GB
- Graphics Intel GMA HD

Im using Ubuntu 10.10 . I do not have this problem in Ubuntu 10.04 , but this problem occur in Ubuntu 10.10 . I can't decrease or increase my brightness even in Compiz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have an ACER, but ASPIRE 4736Z. Same problem.

xbacklight, xgamma doesn't work.

Something that did work for me is redshift utility:
[Is there a software utility to adjust screen gamma/brightness/contrast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9248/is-there-a-software-utility-to-adjust-screen-gamma-brightness-contrast)

Comment: thx ^^ gonna try it

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

1. Open the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Change the line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```

   To:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
   ```
3. Save the file and quit the text editor.
4. Now in the terminal run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Restart Ubuntu.

*Based very closely on this article: [living in java](http://livinginjava.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-1010-brightness-problem-in-acer.html)*

Comment: This also works for later Ubuntu. Thank you very much, I've been looking for this solution for ages.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/emgd/+bug/711172

Add to [kernel command line](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132):

```
acpi_backlight=vendor
```

And you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Xbacklight?
http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbacklight