# I've just bought my first 23'' monitor. Which settings to tweak to fill myself comfortable with 1920x1080?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, nvidia, fonts

I've just installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my brand new computer with 23" 1920x1080 monitor. This is my first experience with such a large screen resolution. I don't know what settings should be changed but I feel myself uncomfortable. 1920x1080 resolution is very unusual to me.

What did you do to feel comfortable with 1920x1080? Please share your experience. I would also like to know where I can make adjustments to the screen so I can try different settings to find the ones that will make it look better.

Comment: Please split this up into individual questions, the system works best when there's one post per question, thanks!

Comment: @Jorge Castro
I agree that the question is vague. The problem is that I don't know how to formulate my question better. This is my first 23" monitor. Such a big resolution is very unusual to me. I even don't know which settings to tweak to fill myself comfortable.

Comment: If this big resolution is unusual to you, I'd suggest you would change it to a smaller one.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some Appearance related questions that you might want to check out:

- [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/244/what-should-i-set-the-dpi-to-for-my-13-macbook-pro/48083#48083
- [Is there a software utility to adjust screen gamma/brightness/contrast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9248/is-there-a-software-utility-to-adjust-screen-gamma-brightness-contrast)

Answer (score 2):

Going to answer the DPI question:

You want to set the DPI (dots per inch, used by the font renderer) to the PPI (pixel per inch) of your screen, so that a 10 point font is really 10 point on your screen.

Lucky for you, your monitor has 96 pixel per inch (2203 pixels on a 23" diagonal), so you can leave the DPI setting alone and just resize the fonts to your liking (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → gnome-appearance-properties → *Fonts* tab).