# Is there a program that adjusts the screen color depending on the time?

Tags: software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a software utility to adjust screen gamma/brightness/contrast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9248/is-there-a-software-utility-to-adjust-screen-gamma-brightness-contrast)

What is the name of the program that tints the screen color depending on the time?