# Screen Dimming Changed After Upgrade to 15.04?

Tags: display, brightness, 15.04

Up until this week I was able to dim my laptop to a very dim setting, barely any brightness at all, which I liked at night. After upgrading to 15.04, the maximum dim is way brighter than it was before. I lost my ultra-dim capabilities. What happened, and how can I get my ultra-dim options back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing this file:

```
sudo nano /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

May be elsewhere under `/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`

source: [Set brightness lower](http://sudo%20nano%20/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness)

EDIT:

Try reducing the gamma with `redshift`:

[Reducing Contrast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9248/is-there-a-software-utility-to-adjust-screen-gamma-brightness-contrast)

Comment: That file seems to be empty.

Comment: post `ls /sys/class/backlight`

Comment: I found what you're talking about.  `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`. I set the level to "1" to get it as dark as it will go, but it's not very dark at all. I tried 0.1, but got this error: `Unable to save /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
Error: administrator_copy_file(/tmp/.subl1f9.tmp, /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness) failed: Authorization failed`. I guess it can't be set below 1, but somehow I need it to be.

Comment: Good answer. Installed redshift and now if i go `redshift -b 0.1` it makes the screen ridiculously dim. Thanks.