# Adjust color temperature with Intel HD graphics

Tags: intel-graphics, intel

Is there any way to install Intel HD graphics in Ubuntu 
If yes then how?
If no then how I reduce blue color from my lcd

Comment: Intel drivers are already installed.

Comment: So where it is why I m not able to  open it like in windows

Comment: Please read the answer. Nothing else to add. Try to avoid the X-Y Problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: As per the duplicate question, _redshift_ is the package you want to install.

Comment: Hey you celetic whatever I have no XY issue I m just new in Ubuntu so I asking questions

Comment: @dobey - Why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: @CelticWarrior A better link to use for XY problem comments is [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at Meta Stack Exchange, but even so I agree with Shantnu Chaubey that this question is not an XY problem. I've been so impressed with your recent comments that I'm helping you to get better at it. If you delete your XY comment, I'll delete this one and ask a mod to delete Shantnu's XY comment.

Comment: @karel User wants to "reduce blue color" and doesn't know how. User thinks he can fumble is way like in Windows by installing Intel software and opening the settings GUI. That was the question. An X-Y problem. Granted, the user discloses the goal at the very end.

Comment: Shantnu commented and wrote *Yes that's software I looking for*. I only use the XY problem when defending answers that are legitimate solutions to the question. If the OP knew everything in advance then he wouldn't need to ask a question. Using the XY problem to criticize a question may lead to closing the question inappropriately or closing it for the wrong reason which doesn't help the author to solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Edited answer:

I believe the software you are looking for is Redshift [image: redshift]. See this Q&A for how to install it: [Is there a software utility to adjust screen gamma/brightness/contrast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9248/is-there-a-software-utility-to-adjust-screen-gamma-brightness-contrast)

---

## Original answer:

Ubuntu automatically detects and applies the appropriate drivers for chipsets with Intel HD graphics.*

No human intervention required.

The *"blue color"* you speak of is probably a physical defect with the display.

<sup>*Brand new chipsets like KabyLake might have buggy drivers, but they're there nonetheless.</sup>

Comment: No defects I just want less blue colour so my eyes don't stress I am able to reduce blue colour using Intel HD graphics in windows but in Ubuntu there is no option

Comment: @ShantnuChaubey - Oh, I catch your drift now. See this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/q/9248/518562