# Dell Inspiron n5010 Brightness Issue

Tags: dell, brightness

I have recently installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my Dell Inspiron n5010 but screen brightness is not working, there is no effect of pressing fn+brightness keys.

Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: I have exactly the same laptop with 10.10 netbook installed and have no issues - you do not need to use the FN key just press the brightness keys (5th and 6th key on top row)

Comment: Thanks everyone. 

I just updated the BIOS and now brightness is working great.

Comment: Updated the BIOS... Please, provide more details about what exactly you updated/changed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone.

I just updated the BIOS and now brightness is working great.

Comment: How did you do it? Did you do so on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Oxwivi: Updated the BIOS from Windows, but you can do the update also from Linux.

Comment: Ah, I see. Click on tick mark on the left of your answer to let others know that it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to choose Dell Inspiron as your keyboard layout in the keyboard section of Administration. I had to do this with my Fujitsu Seimens Lappy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this laptop has the same problem as my Acer Aspire 4736Z.

These solutions might help you:

- [Can't adjust brightness on my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9047/cant-adjust-brightness-on-my-laptop)
- [Is there a software utility to adjust screen gamma/brightness/contrast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9248/is-there-a-software-utility-to-adjust-screen-gamma-brightness-contrast)

Answer (score 0):

Such shortcuts are handled by the `udev` subsystem. The configuration files exist in /lib/udev/.

The way it works is that you add a description of your laptop in /lib/udev/keymaps, and then activate it for your laptop in /lib/udev/rules.d/.
There is more to the description I provide. You would need to read how similar laptop variants are handled already to get your laptop supported.

Answer (score 0):

I also have have Dell Inspiron N5010 model, Brightness settings works fine for me with Ubuntu 10.10 64bit. You dont need to press fn key to adjust the brightness.