# Cannot change brightness on an Acer Aspire 5745-dg

Tags: laptop, brightness, acer

I have an acer aspire 5745dg laptop and i have also a very serious problem!!

My brightness is always at maximun and I cannot change it with the fn keys or from the power management and my battery discharging fast:/.

Thats my problem and i need your help guys!!!!In my windows partition brightness works perfectly only in ubuntu I have this serious and annoying problem!!!!Please reply to my message i'd appreciate that!

Comment: Hi, welcome to AU. Can you change the brightness from the "Screen" setting application? Search "bright" in the dash.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also own a Acer netbook. I use

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=XX
```

where XX is your brightness level.

```
XX = FF for max brightness
XX = 30 my setting
XX = 00 no brightness
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

([Source](http://livinginjava.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-1010-brightness-problem-in-acer.html))

1. Open the grub configuration file.

   ```
    gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Find this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` and change it to:

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
   ```
3. Save the file and close the text editor.
4. Update Grub.

   ```
    sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Restart your computer and try to change the brightness.

## Similar Question

["Can't Adjust Brightness on My Laptop"](https://askubuntu.com/q/9047/3780)

Comment: i tried it but nothnig happened anything else?:/

Comment: I would look at the link I posted labeled "Can't adjust brightness on my laptop" and try the other things there. They had an Acer too.