# I can't dim my laptop's light

Tags: acer, backlight

I can't modify my laptop brightness. Is it a BIOS problem? It works in win 7, but doesn't work in Ubuntu. It's an Acer Aspire 5750-6842 laptop with Intel HD graphics 3000 video chipset.

Comment: Might be an issue common to aspire line of laptops, give [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9047/cant-adjust-brightness-on-my-laptop) a look and see if any of the answers there help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved a similar brightness issue on my Toshiba Satellite the easy way:

http://prahladyeri.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/how-to-make-brightness-changes-permanent-in-your-linux-desktop/