# How to lower monitor screen brightness?

Tags: 10.10, screen, brightness

I'm using **10.10 ubuntu** and i want to reduce my **screen brightness**. In **windows 7** option like **calibrate color** is available by which i have reduced brightness, is there any thing i can do in ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 is not officially supported anymore so questions about Ubuntu 10.10 are marked as off topic in this site. You should upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu. If you want stability, you should use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which is a long term support version and will be supported until 2017. Ubuntu 13.10(the latest version) is buggy for many users who have old hardware.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't adjust brightness on my laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9047/cant-adjust-brightness-on-my-laptop)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your function keys are working. 
If not you can use [Brightness Controller](http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/), a free and open source app.

It is not available on the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 10.10 so you have to install it from the [.deb package](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84627545/brightness_1.0.1_all.deb).

Let me know if the .deb package is working in Ubuntu 10.10.